# When I try to boot from live cd I get a blank screen HELP!

Tags: 11.10, boot, graphics, live-cd, screen

I've created a bootable USB and tried a Live CD. Both times when I boot from them I can hear the Ubuntu drums but have only a blank screen. I have an Asus with quad core A6 processor and Radeon HD 6720G2 graphics card.

What should I do to solve this?

**P.S.** works fine with wubi.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem. But I didn't hear the login sound, just saw the black screen. The --nomodeset boot option helped to solve the problem. [Read there for more info](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions)